# HABTM timely response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for an alternative way to check if ActivityType has any relationships as the way I am doing it now is too costly (**`activity_type.activities.empty?`**).

I thought about creating a new method such as **`ActivityType#linked_to_activity?`** which would do a query on ActivitiesActivityTypes HABTM join table. This is faster than the previously mentioned method but it is still too slow.

Any pointers are appreciated (apart from the usual "*HABTM should be replaced by HM:through*" non-constructive comment)

**Models**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activity_types, :uniq => true
end

class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
end
```

**View**

```
%table
  - @activity_types.each do |activity_type|
    %tr
      %td
        - if activity_type.activities.empty?
          Do something here...
```

**Attempt at ActivityType#linked_to_activity?**

```
class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities

  def linked_to_activity?
    ActivityType.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM activities_activity_types WHERE activity_type_id = ?", id]).empty? ? false : true
  end
end
```

**NB:**

- Running on Rails v2.3.5
- DB is MySQL with indices on foreign keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. It's a matter of preference, but I usually do it with a count:

```
class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities

  def linked_to_activity?
    self.activities.count > 0
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

As the comment below states: Using `select count(*)` will only retrieve one line from the DB, while `select *` retrieves all (unless of course you add a `limit 1` at the end).

Also: I try not to litter my models with plain SQL unless it's absolutely necessary for performance reasons.

Comment: You could improve your answer telling why the 'count' method is better - explain that it automatically issues the `SELECT count(*)` query instead of fetching all the objects with standard `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thanks, your count (925ms) suggestion worked a lot better than my embedded sql (2460ms).

Answer (score 2):

This should improve the performance of your `#linked_to_activity?`:

```
class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities

  def linked_to_activity?
    ActivityType.count_by_sql(["SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activities_activity_types WHERE activity_type_id = ?", id]) > 0
  end
end
```